# Unexpected output after return statement

Tags: java

I have following code:

```
public class MainClass {

    static int someStaticVariable = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MainClass obj = new MainClass();
        obj.someInstanceMethod();
        System.out.println("Count in main method " + someStaticVariable);
    }

    public int someInstanceMethod() {

        String someString = "line1\nline2\n";

        System.out.println("Count in someInstanceMethod method "
                    + (someStaticVariable + someString.split("\r\n|\r|\n").length));

        return (someStaticVariable + someString.split("\r\n|\r|\n").length);

    }
}
```

***Question: Why the output is:***

```
Count in someInstanceMethod method 2
Count in main method 0
```

***and not***

```
Count in someInstanceMethod method 2
Count in main method 2
```

and why it prints out to `Count in someInstanceMethod method 2` in someInstanceMethod and returning `0` and then printing `0` in main method.

Comment: You never changed `someStaticVariable`, you just print out `someString.split("\r\n|\r|\n").length)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't assign anything to `someStaticVariable`; you ignored the return of `someInstanceMethod`.  Try

```
someStaticVariable = obj.someInstanceMethod();
```

Or, you can assign it in the method itself.

```
someStaticVariable += someString.split("\r\n|\r|\n").length;
return (someStaticVariable + someString.split("\r\n|\r|\n").length);
```

Comment: ok, this was working fine, but `someStaticVariable` is static variable I can use it directly without assigning if I am not wrong, as I had already changed its value in `someInstanceMethod`?

Comment: You didn't change its value in `someInstanceMethod`.  As my answer points out, you need to either assign the return value to `someStaticVariable` or actually change its value in `someInstanceMethod`.

Comment: @Vishrant `static` means that you can reference the variable without creating an object of the class first - not that it magically bypasses the need to assign new values to it.

Comment: @rgettman thanks, but then I could have used instance variable, but i have used static method so that if its value is changed in any method it will reflect in all the method, but why this is not so in this case.

Comment: @Vishrant *Because you didn't change the value*. Using does not equate to changing. That variable will not change unless you **explicitly** assign a new value to it.

Comment: @Vishrant In Java, `static` doesn't make a difference as to how a variable's value is assigned.  It has nothing to do with it.  Just assign a new value to the variable.

Comment: @JonK yes sir got your point. :) I must say what a silly mistake by me, any ways thanks, appreciate that.

Comment: @rgettman yup got the point thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you do not tamper with `someStaticVariable`.

You simply print out the sum of `someStaticVariable` (which is 0) and `someString.split("\r\n|\r|\n").length`

What you need to do is assignment:

```
someStaticVariable = obj.someInstanceMethod();
```

Comment: `someStaticVariable` is tampered in `someInstanceMethod` method and then it is printed in `main` method

Comment: You don't assign it in that method.

Comment: yup after assigning it was working fine. but I have changed value `someStaticVariable` in `someInstanceMethod` then why I need to assign, why I can not directly use that variable as it is static and it has scope in both the method